# when i creating react native app most of my files are in kotlin instead of java

Tags: android, react-native

Whenever I create a react native app, most of my file are in kotlin e.g MainActivity.kt, please is there a way to make my default files to be in java?

Comment: As of react native 73 kotlin is used as default. Android Studio even have a tool that can help you convert java files into kotlin [link](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/12/06/0.73-debugging-improvements-stable-symlinks#kotlin-template-on-android)

Answer (score 3):

React Native community appears to have a template that still uses Java as the basis of the Android side. You can use it in a new project like so:

```bash
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript@6.12.10
```

I would suggest just creating a second project and copy-pasting the Android contents of that project into your actual one.

That said, I think it is worth noting that Kotlin is fully compatible with Java, and that Kotlin is the preferred basis for Android projects these days. It would be worthwhile becoming familiar with the language.

Answer (score 1):

react native 0.73.x generates Kotlin template by default.

To install java template, follow, react native guideline to install react native 0.72.10 which was the last react native version with default java template.

Create a new project with this cmd.

```
npx react-native@0.72.10 init AwesomeProject --version 0.72.10
```

you can also install template with `--template` argument,
but the react native docs are not clear on that as how to generate java template with latest react native version.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup